# scala comma separated string to double-quoted comma separated string

Tags: scala

I have a file which contains certain string like -

```
Apple
Google
Microsoft
```

I am reading in this file as

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filePath).mkString.replace("\n", ",")
```

Which results in a comma separated list of string. However what I really want is `"Apple","Google","Microsoft"`

If I add double quotes in the string replace while reading in the file I while have to take care of the first and last double quotes which won't be ideal. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to load each line into an `Iterator` and then let `mkString` apply the commas and quote marks.

```
io.Source
  .fromFile(filePath)
  .getLines()
  .mkString("\"","\",\"","\"")
//res0: String = "Apple","Google","Microsoft"
```

Comment: The output for me is now looking like - 
"A","p","p","l","e".......

Comment: Are you using `.getLines` (and only `.getLines`) to read from the file?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to jwvh's answer but with `Using` for resource management

```
import scala.util.Using
import scala.io.Source

Using.resource(Source.fromFile(filePath)) { file =>
  file.getLines.map(line => s""""$line"""").mkString(",")
}
```